# Is there a way I can make an action button reactive inside the server function to display an output?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I am developing a shiny app, where I want my action button to be created and be reactive from the server part of my code and show an output.

My current code looks like:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      body {
      background-color: #black
      }"))),br(),
  titlePanel(h1("Query Engine", align = 'Center')),br(),
  #helpText("", align='Center'),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( width = 3,
                  sliderInput("amnt", label='Amount (USD)',
                              min= as.integer(min(df$gross_amount))-1, max=as.integer((max(df$gross_amount)))+1, #subtract/add 1 cuz cutting off the cents
                              value = c(min(df$gross_amount),max(df$gross_amount)), step = 0),
                  
                  uiOutput("date"), #input#1
                  uiOutput("customer"), #input#2
                  uiOutput("id"), #input#3
                  actionButton("btn","Summary", width = '100%'), br()
    ),

mainPanel(
     tabPanel("1", value = "check1", DT::dataTableOutput("table_subset1")),
tabPanel("2", value = "check2", DT::dataTableOutput("table_subset2"))

)
      
    )
  )
)
#################  Server_Part ################# 
 df$Check_Name[df$check_id==1 ]<- data.table(as.character(actionButton("btn1","Creation")))


  submit1 <- eventReactive(input$btn1,{
    idfilter <- df_filtered1()[ , c('id','company','code','amount','gst', 'hst_amount','currency')]
  })
  
  # this is the output which we are showing:
  output$table_subset1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(distinct(submit1()), options = list(scrollX = T))
  })

 observeEvent(input$btn1, {updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabset1", selected = "check1")})
```

This is just a dummy code and dummy data, the main thing is that my action button is appearing successfully but its not reactive. Can someone please help me figure out what wrong am i doing?

This is a picture of the output:

[image]

As can be seen the action button gets created but it's not reactive.

Comment: Why are you creating an action button in server part? What stopping you from creating it in UI part?

Comment: its a business requirement, to let the user button see the tabset output if "the user wants to see the details".

Having in UI part makes it a little redundant as same information shows up in the dataframe output. So we thought okay why not make the dataframe output an action button.

I was able to do that, but not its just not working sadly. I am open to using HTML or  javascript here as well but so far i am not able to even make something like action button using HTML or javascript.

Comment: SInce you did not provide MWE, I can only guess - is this created inside module? If so an id of a button differs from id you are observing, if you create a button like this.

Comment: how so? the action button id is "btn1" and the observeEvent input is "btn1"

The output which i want to show is for submit1 <- event function which also has "btn1" as input :O

Comment: if i put this action button is ui, everything works like a charm.

Comment: If you put your actionButton in a `renderUI` that should work. Your code is not understandable so it's difficult to help.

Comment: sorry about that, i tried to add some details now since im a new member i cant edit my own question

Comment: you can use `uiOutput` and `renderUI` to add in an `actionButton` or any other tag, or you can also you `insertUI` to insert it directly from the server to a specific location